# Getting out of the question ban

Tags: support, reputation, post-ban

I've been trying for months now to get out of the question ban. I commented, accepted and upvoted every useful answer I got for my questions. I remained civil and polite at them, too. I edited every single question I ever asked to the point, that all of them have at least score 0, aside from that one:

[Java build path errors on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373594/java-build-path-errors-on-eclipse)

The downvoters never bothered though to explain what could I possibly improve. I tried also to make positive contributions, by answering questions and scoring about 300+ reputation since the ban. Look, I'm not mad at the system or something. I just really want to be a good programmer and a useful advisor here in the future, but I really don't know what else I could do. If I can know this without asking this question, please point me to a source when I can learn it (although I read every single tip on writing good answers and asking good questions).

If you know what is wrong, I'd be really grateful if you could point specifically which question needs fixing and how. If this question is inappropriate for any reason, please explain why and advise me where to move it.

Comment: I assume you've seen this, but you should first read [the FAQ articles on bans](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/263510). Do you have a lot of deleted posts?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like your efforts paid off. From what I can see, your ban has been automatically lifted by the system.

If you want to avoid going through this again, you may want to avoid deleting your own posts because doing so tends to hurt your standing. In the [FAQ article on bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/238110) states:

> It's not a problem to have deleted posts. But if a large percentage of
>   your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently
>   they are not suitable for the site. Posting them consumes time from
>   users who read them, edit them, or respond to them. Therefore deleted
>   posts have an effect on the filter, among many other factors.

I can't say for sure whether that caused your ban, but it certainly didn't help.

Nice job learning and improving based on the system's feedback. Enjoy!